# Keycode authentication to access webapp

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a surprise website for my friend and I wanted it to be fun -- in the homepage, I wanted to build a simple keycode access (very similar to iphone's enter-your-keycode homescreen) page such that access to the rest of the webapp is only possible if the keycode entered in the homepage is right.

How do i go about doing this? I'm new to django, and i only know how to do username-password authentication. How do i create a key-code access and that only by having the right keycode can anyone see the rest of the website?

Thank you so much!

Comment: sounds like you need to make a Html page, and then use javascript.  Remember, Django is the framework to implement Python based webapplications.  if it is visual it is likely html/css.  If it involved data access and computation, it is python... and if it is clientside, it is javascript.

Comment: ahhh, if its javascript (aka clientsided), then will the access key make sure that non-authenticated users will not be able to view any of the rest of the webapp?

Comment: you would use javascript to handle the presses and then submit the request to an endpoint written in python, likely encrypted in some way.  You could have the access key be stored client side in javascript or html by way of django injection but it isnt secure.  So the best way is to submit it by an end point for validation.  If you are just showing a friend though....  im not sure what levels of security etc you are wanting to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a middleware with methods like these:

```
def _unauthorized(self):
    response = HttpResponse("""<html><title>Auth required</title><body>
                            <h1>Authorization Required</h1></body></html>""", content_type="text/html")
    response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="My Site Name"'
    response.status_code = 401
    return response

def process_request(self, request):
    if validate:
        if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in request.META:
            return self._unauthorized()
        else:
            authentication = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
            (authmeth, auth) = authentication.split(' ', 1)
            if 'basic' != authmeth.lower():
                return self._unauthorized()
            auth = auth.strip().decode('base64')
            username, password = auth.split(':', 1)
            if username == <USERNAME> and password == <PASSWORD>:
                return None

            return self._unauthorized()
```

That would require anyone to enter a username and password to view the site.
That's not exactly "keycode access" but you could just give a short username and password.